# How to (portably) get DBL_EPSILON in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

I am using GCC 3.4 on Linux (AS 3) and trying to figure out to get `DBL_EPSILON`, or at least a decent approximation.  How can I get it programmatically?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217284/whats-the-smallest-non-zero-positive-floating-point-number-in-perl/1217509#1217509 and

Comment: One thing nobody talked about below and that is important: any definition of Epsilon's value is a bet that comes out of nowhere (or almost). I mean, this a reasonable value defined for resonable computations. The very nature of reals on computers is that they are not exact value (bin vs dec). So any computation widens the gap between the computed and the theoritical values.  Epsilon is for this gap.  If you really make a lot of computations, you might well end up with this gap being greater than the standard epsilon. Be always extremely careful with reals on computers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It should be in "float.h". That is portable, it's part of the C and C++ standards (albeit deprecated in C++ - use `<cfloat>` or sbi's answer for "guaranteed" forward compatibility).

If you don't have it, then since your doubles are IEEE 64-bit, you can just steal the value from someone else's float.h. Here's the first one I found:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-937.2/float.h

`#define DBL_EPSILON 2.2204460492503131e-16`

The value looks about right to me, but if you want to be sure on your compiler, you could check that `(1.0 + DBL_EPSILON) != 1.0 && (1.0 + DBL_EPSILON/2) == 1.0`

Edit: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "programmatically". It's a standard constant, you aren't supposed to calculate it, it's a property of the implementation given to you in a header file. But I guess you could do something like this. Again, assuming IEEE representation or something like it, so that DBL_EPSILON is bound to be whatever power of 0.5 represents a 1 in the last bit of precision of the representation of 1.0:

```
double getDblEpsilon(void) {
    double d = 1;
    while (1.0 + d/2 != 1.0) {
        d = d/2;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Beware that depending on compiler settings, intermediate results might have higher precision than `double`, in which case you'd get a smaller result for `d` than `DBL_EPSILON`. Check your compiler manual, or find a way to force the value of `1.0 + d/2` to be stored and reloaded to an actual `double` object before you compare it to `1.0`. Very roughly speaking, on PCs it depends on whether your compiler uses the x86 FPU instructions (higher precision), or newer x64 floating point ops (double precision).

Comment: how to get it programmatically?

Comment: I suspect `while ((double)(1.0 + d/2) != 1.0) {` would handle the "intermediate results might have higher precision than `double`"
 issue.

Answer (score 41):

In C++ it's `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`.

Comment: The header file is <limits>

Comment: You're welcome. One more thing to be aware of is that it does not throw an exception if there is no epsilon. It just quietly returns zero. (At least on MSVC++ 2010) cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::epsilon() << endl;

Comment: @JiveDadson epsilon for `int` does not make sense. I guess that's why you are expecting an exception?