# Convert double to int in C++ without round down errors

Tags: c++, casting, int, double

I have the following codes to cast a `double` into an `int`:

```
double dblValue = 7.30;
int intValue = (int)(dblValue*100);  //I want intValue to store exactly 730;
std::cout << intValue;
```

**Output: `729`**

I know that the compiler is reading `dblValue` as `7.2999999` before casting it to `int`.

**My question is**: Is it possible to cast it as `730` by preventing the round down errors?

It would be best if your solution avoid using C++11 or other predefined functions. The only pre-processor directive I am using here is `<iostream>`.

Comment: Try `int intValue = (int)(dblValue*100.0);`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for your reply, but it still gives 729..

Comment: There's also the `ceil()` functíon to perform an explcit uprounding.

Comment: try rounding up "int intValue = (int)((dblValue*100) + 0.5);"  not completely sure this will work, but it shouldn't hurt, although this isn't pretty.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm getting 730 with the exact code you posted, compiling with no flags.

Comment: Actually, I tried `int intValue = (int)(dblValue*100.1);` and it works, but I feel that it is hard-coding. Do you guys think it is fine? Thanks!

Comment: If you can't use math.h, but want `round()`s behavior then just [implement a concise version yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4572877/2167797).

Comment: @user3437460: when the floating point value is known to roughly an integer, use the +0.5 exemplified by dboals, combined with a range check before conversion.

Comment: What about introducing [`std::numeric_limits::epsilon`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) for solutions?

Answer (score 25):

You cannot prevent rounding errors when converting a number that is not an integer (in the mathematical sense) to an integer, the only thing you can do is try to achieve proper rounding.

The easiest way to achieve a sensible (although not perfect) rounding is the following:

```
int intValue = (int)(dblValue < 0 ? dblValue - 0.5 : dblValue + 0.5);
```

And of course, since your question is tagged both `c++` and `casting` I cannot resist replacing your c-style cast with a c++ style cast:

```
int intValue = static_cast<int>(dblValue < 0 ? dblValue - 0.5 : dblValue + 0.5);
```

Comment: **+1** My daily vote limit is reached, but I would upvote here!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Damn, I can feel fake internet points slipping through my hands :(

Comment: range check would be nice

Comment: Why not just use `std::round` (converting the results to `int` if they fit)?

Comment: @gha.st _'I can feel fake internet points slipping through my hands :('_ Do you actually have any cyborganic SO interfaces installed to your body? ;) ... I thought ths comment might encourage others to upvote your answer (which apparently happened).

Comment: Because the OP wishes a solution that does not use any predefined functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own integer truncation function that increases the value by the smallest possible amount, to make sure the rounded result is over the integer threshold.

```
#include <limits>

int int_cast(double x)
{
    return (int)(x * (1.0 + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()));
}
```

If you don't want to depend on `<limits>` you can use `DBL_EPSILON` from `<float.h>` or substitute your own very small number. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566198/how-to-portably-get-dbl-epsilon-in-c-c).

Answer (score 1):

C++11 added [lround](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) that helps to avoid precision loss on implicit double to long truncating cast:

```
int intValue = (int) lround(dblValue*100)
```

`long` to `int` cast won't loose precision too.

There is no `iround()`, unfortunately.

**Update**

I guess there is no `iround()` because any 32-bit integer will allways fit completely in 52 [precision bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) of 64-bit double. So there is no chance of precision loss on direct double to int truncation:

```
int intValue = (int) round(dblValue*100)
```

Comment: Unless you specifically want the special rounding mode used by `round`, use `long i = lrint(x);` or `int i = (int)nearbyint(x);`.  [round() for float in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347224)

Answer (score 0):

It's not any type of error, it's the way computer stores floating-point values.
You can do something like this:

```
int intValue = (int)(dblValue*100 + 0.00001);
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't purely due to the way computers store floating-point values.  You'd have the same problems converting a mathematical real to a mathematical integer.

Comment: not to mention this doesn't fix negative numbers or rounding up on the half